# Tracking robot position during teleoperation

Tags: ros, navigation, navfn, teleop, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
**I want to track robot's current position when it is moved by teleop( which we can view in rviz  window as well)**

ROS ***automatic behavior also need to perform similar kind of stuff during goal position achievement***.

So, now **which packages or exactly which part of ROS does similar** kind of stuff?  (THIS HAS BEEN SORTED OUT WHICH IS amcl)

***Where the processing related to comparison of current goal (x,y,z) and sub goal  is done?***

***Where the goal and subgoal location is stored in move_base package?***

**Question:3 SO WHENEVER I CLICK SET GOAL in RVIZ, where does the GOAL LOCATION is SAVED EXACTLY?**

Thank you for any kind of help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130541/tracking-robot-position-during-teleoperation/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS navigation usually uses AMCL to track and publish the location of the robot, in combination with the robot's odometry.

AMCL usually publishes the position of the robot as a TF transform from the /map frame to the /base_link frame.

To understand how rviz interacts with the navigation stack, take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack

You can also use the `rostopic`, `rosnode` and `rqt_graph` tools to introspect a running system, to see which topics exist and how they're connected.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-02-18**:
@thanks for the answer. I have gone through http://wiki.ros.org/amcl. I think by listening into the amcl_pose topic, we can get the robot's position wrt the map. Global plan is completed before the robot movement in rviz; so whenever I click set goal in rviz, I need that goal location to be saved in some text file. In amcl_node.cpp, I only found some gui_publish_period, can't able to locate exactly how various navigation packages interacts dynamically with rviz. I only know that last plan is computed by navfn package. Is there any material or paper related to this issue?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-03-02**:
Does anyone have the answer for 3rd Question?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-02**:
You should be able to find the goal topic by reading the rviz tutorial that I linked to. Read section 4 carefully.